# How to get all images in a folder using CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying get all images which are located in standard cakePHP image folder. I am using:

```
App::uses('Folder', 'Utility');
App::uses('File', 'Utility');
$dir = new Folder('/app/webroot/img/');
$files = $dir->find('.*\.png');

pr($files);
```

but i always get empty array. Where is the problem?

Ina addition when I try make dir in that folder i get error:

```
mkdir(): No such file or directory [CORE\Cake\Utility\Folder.php, line 515]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing `new Folder('/app/webroot/img/');` you're actually saying your app folder is in the root of the drive, and since it isn't, CakePHP will try and create it, which it can't (that mkdir error).

You probably need to do something like

`$dir = new Folder(App.imageBaseUrl);`

or

`$dir = new Folder(APP_DIR . DS . "webroot" . DS . "img");`.

Check the constants CakePHP gives you to handle paths http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html#core-definition-constants should be usefull

Comment: You can also just use `glob()`.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing the answer is given and accepted, 
This is a right way given by the documents.

```
<?php
// Find all .png in your app/webroot/img/ folder and sort the results
$dir = new Folder(WWW_ROOT . 'img');
$files = $dir->find('.*\.png', true);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/file-folder.html#Folder::find